# Action Bar Sherlock Holo.Light Theme in Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to make my application compatible for all android versions from 3.0+. My action bar works fine in the versions 4.0+ but I'm currently getting this error when I try to run it on the honeycomb emulator:

> 04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chartviewer/com.example.chartviewer.JsonActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1003)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:849)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at com.example.chartviewer.JsonActivity.onCreate(JsonActivity.java:88)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
>   04-12 03:28:49.525: E/AndroidRuntime(1447):     ... 11 more

Here is my Action Bar code :

```
<style name="Theme.mmcv" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

   <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_mmcv</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mmcv_solid_ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/mmcv_ActionBarTabStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="mmcv_solid_ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_mmcv</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_mmcv</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_mmcv</item>

</style>

<style name="mmcv_ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_mmcv</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the error message:

> You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative

rather than your current Theme.Holo.Light

I would suggest looking over the [ActionBarSherlock theming](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) page or looking over the results from a [Theme generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to get the appropriate ActionBarSherlock attributes.